Script for automatic Windows installation keeps restarting from the beginning of the setup
Whenever I start the script via the shell, it apparently executes the tasks and restarts as requested. However, it always restarts from the beginning of the setup as if it had done nothing at all. Does anyone have any idea how I can change this so that it installs the complete operating system and I can then log in as with a normal manual installation?
$regKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\MySetupScript"
$regValueName = "CurrentTask"

# Check if the script has already been executed
if (Test-Path $regKey) {
    $currentTask = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $regKey).$regValueName
    if ($currentTask) {
        Write-Host "The script has already been started. Proceeding to the next task: $currentTask"
        Goto $currentTask
    }
}

# Infinite loop that will only break once the setup is completed
while ($true) {
    # Task 1: Create user
    :CreateUser
    $username = "TESTUSER"
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "test123" -AsPlainText -Force
    New-LocalUser -Name $username -Password $password -FullName $username -Description "$username user created" -PasswordNeverExpires:$true

    # Task 2: Disable privacy settings
    :SetupPrivacySettings
    Write-Host "Disabling privacy settings..."
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Privacy" -Name "TailoredExperiencesWithDiagnosticDataEnabled" -Value 0
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection" -Name "AllowTelemetry" -Value 0
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection" -Name "AllowTailoredExperiencesWithDiagnosticData" -Value 0
    Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection" -Name "DisableTailoredExperiencesWithDiagnosticData" -Value 1

    # Task 3: Change region and keyboard layout
    :SetupRegionAndKeyboard
    Write-Host "Changing region and keyboard layout..."
    Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale "de-DE"
    Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList "de-DE" -Force
    Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language "de-DE" -Force
    Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList "de-DE" -Force
    Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride -InputTip "0407:00000407" -Language "de-DE"

    # Task 4: Change computer name
    :ChangeComputerName
    Write-Host "Changing computer name..."
    Rename-Computer -NewName "Workstation9" -Force

    # All tasks completed, break the loop
    Write-Host "Setup completed."
    Remove-Item -Path $regKey -Force
    break
}

# Restart the computer
Write-Host "Restarting computer..."
Restart-Computer -Force
exit

An unattend.xml is unfortunately out of the question for me because the image is already on our new devices.`
I have adjusted the script several times but unfortunately without success

Have you run the script manually? Goto is not a powershell command. Even if you define/import it from somewhere else, nothing is actually updating the $regKeyor$regValueName values between steps, so the status will never change between runs

The registry key is not getting set so you code always starts from the beginning.  It may be you credentials are not allowing the registry key to get set.  Use Regedit and search for "MySetupScript" and see if the key is getting set some place else in the registry.

Include the reset at the end of the while loop.

When i add the Reset command to the While loop its still restarting  at beginns at the start of the Setup

Yes the key didnt get set but why?

It's not really clear what you expect the script to do. You currently have, in order: 1) set reg key 2) run some setup commands 3) Unset the reg key 4) reboot at the end. If the script runs all the way through, then the key should get removed. Also, I don't see any reason to have a While loop at all here, and please read through about_Continue for how the :LabelName syntax is used in powershell
